# Is is any way to show errors in the corresponding form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-handling, razor-pages, modelstate

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor Pages and MVC application.
It is quite simple when it is only one form on a page, but how correctly show the errors when there are few forms?

Example:
/ManageUser.cshtml

```html
<div>
  <form method="post">
    <div class="validation-summary-valid text-danger" asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="OldPassword"></label>
      <input asp-for="OldPassword" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="NewPassword1"></label>
      <input asp-for="NewPassword1" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="NewPassword2"></label>
      <input asp-for="NewPassword2" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-page-handler="ChangePassword">Change password</button>
  </form>
</div>

<!-- let's say it is the other "tab" -->
<div>
  <form method="post">
    <div class="validation-summary-valid text-danger" asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="ChangeEmail"></label>
      <input asp-for="ChangeEmail" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-page-handler="ChangeEmail">Change email</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

And, if on the backend side any error is found:

```csharp
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostChangeEmailAsync([FromService] UserManager<User> userManager)
{
  //... skipped for brevity
  ModelState.AddModelError("", "User not found or deleted");

  return Page();
}
```

then this error is shown for both forms. Any way to show it for corresponding form only?

PS: Please do not propose to make the errors field-bound: it is not the case and the fields in the example is just for the simplicity.

Comment: Do you want to verify each form individually or just display the verification message in the corresponding position?

Comment: @Yinqiu, yes you are right, I want to verify each form individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking field validation as an example, you can try the following code.

View:

```
    <div>
    <form method="post">
        <span class="text-danger">@Html.ValidationMessage("PasswordError")</span>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="UserModel.OldPassword"></label>
            <input asp-for="UserModel.OldPassword" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="UserModel.OldPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="UserModel.NewPassword1"></label>
            <input asp-for="UserModel.NewPassword1" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="UserModel.NewPassword1" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="UserModel.NewPassword2"></label>
            <input asp-for="UserModel.NewPassword2" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="UserModel.NewPassword2" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-page-handler="ChangePassword">Change password</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <form method="post">
        <span class="text-danger">@Html.ValidationMessage("EmailError")</span>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="UserModel.ChangeEmail"></label>
            <input asp-for="UserModel.ChangeEmail" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="UserModel.ChangeEmail" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-page-handler="ChangeEmail">Change email</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The backend side(you can remove the attributes):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostChangeEmailAsync(UserModel userModel)
    {
        
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ModelState.Remove("UserModel.OldPassword");
            ModelState.Remove("UserModel.NewPassword1");
            ModelState.Remove("UserModel.NewPassword2");
            ModelState.AddModelError("EmailError", "User not found or deleted");
        }
        return Page();
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostChangePassword(UserModel userModel)
    {
       
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ModelState.Remove("UserModel.ChangeEmail");
            ModelState.AddModelError("PasswordError", "Password is inconsistent ");
        }
        return Page();
        
    }
```

Result:
[image]